# Multiple radio fields and jQuery AJAX POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, radio-group

I have a list of files that have been uploaded by users. The administrator of the website uses this list to approve/deny user avatar uploads that have been uploaded to a family friendly web application. In the left column of the table we have the avatar, in the right column we have a unique radio group per row with three options:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="<?php echo $uploadId ?>" value="ignore" checked="" /> Ignore</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="<?php echo $uploadId ?>" value="approve" /> Approve</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="<?php echo $uploadId ?>" value="deny" /> Deny</label>
```

The form is submitted using a jQuery AJAX post:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'avatar-decision.php',
    data: "MY-PROBLEM-IS-THIS-BIT",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(htmldata) {
        if (htmldata.result === "success") {
             $('#requestMsg').html(htmldata.msg);
             $('#requestListing').get("avatar-listing.php");
        }  else {
             $('#requestMsg').html(htmldata.msg);
        }
}});
```

I would like to set the value of the `data` field above to capture all the names and values of the radio groups submitted. For example, if I have 5 radio groups with the names of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 I would like to capture the value of each radio set and set them in the data value of my ajax post like a query string:

`1=approved&2=ignore&3=deny&4=approve&5=approve`

which follows the structure of:

`[radio-group-name]=[radio-group-value]`

Which means I can then collect them in `request-listing.php`, loop through them and act on them according to their value.

Many thanks,
Arbiter

Comment: Why you don't use `.serialize()`?

Comment: Is there a submit-Button near each radiogroup? If so I'd try to use its click-event to get the radios for this particular avatar.

Comment: No all of the radio groups on the page are submitted with one button

Comment: then @hindmost is right. Use $('#yourform').serialize() as 'data' (see http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: Can I ask why the down vote? You can't just down vote without commenting as I see nothing wrong with the question. I don't know JS. The question is well versed and I've shown my code examples. Thanks for the `.serialize()` suggestion this is my first time really diving in to JS and I'm picking up quite a few bits and bobs - what a useful function! :) Thanks again (+1 hindmost)

Answer (score 0):

a short answer but i think this is just what you need.

```
var array = [];
$("input:radio").each(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
      array[$(this).attr('name')] = 'approved';
    }else{
      array[$(this).attr('name')] = 'discard';
    }                                                               
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**All credit goes to @hindmost who answered this for me in the comments below my question.**

The solution was a dead simply one liner:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'pages/licence-manager/request-decision.php',
    data: $('#requestForm').serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(htmldata) {
        if (htmldata.result === "success") {
            $('#requestMsg').html(htmldata.msg);
            $('#requestListing').get("pages/licence-manager/request-listing.php");
        }  else {
            $('#requestMsg').html(htmldata.msg);
        }
    }
});
```

See the data value:

`$('#avatarForm').serialize();`

That one line solved the whole problem.

Thank you!
Arbiter